# Где ошибка в коде ?? LINQ to XML

Tags: linq2xml

Приветствую! Подскажите , где тут ошибка. Подчеркивает в самом низу `Interfaces`.

Use of unassigned local variable 'Interfaces'

```
public static void Create_Interfaces()
    {
          XDocument Interfaces;
        List<string> intf = new List<string>{"em0","em1","em2"};

        foreach (var i in intf)
        {
            Interfaces = new XDocument(
          new XElement("Interfaces",
            new XElement("Interface",
              new XElement("name", i),
              new XElement("vlan-tagging", XElement.EmptySequence),
              new XElement("unit",
              new XElement("vlan-id", "10"),
              new XElement("family", new XElement("inet", new XElement("address", new XElement("name", "10.10.1.23/24"))))))));
        }
        Interfaces.Save("Interfaces.xml");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С одной стороны вроде бы можно подумать, что **interfaces** инициализируется в цикле **foreach** и по идее не может быть непроинициализированной (и это в общем-то верно). Но с другой стороны компилятор  не может точно знать, что в переменной **intf** есть что итерировать с помощью  **foreach** (иными словами, он не в курсе, выполнится ли цикл хотя бы раз).  Получается, что возможна ситуация, когда ваша переменная **interfaces** останется непроинициализированной, а потому компилятор сигнализирует об ошибке.  На самом деле теоретически разработчики компилятора могли бы попыхтеть и заставить компилятор анализировать подобные конструкции и заранее предсказывать поведение цикла (уж если для человекао это вполне очевидно, то компилятор смог бы это понимать еще лучше), однако они, видимо, не стали усложнять себе и компилятору работу и просто заставили его выдавать сообщение об ощибке в том числе и в такой очевидной ситуации

```
public static void Create_Interfaces()
    {
        var interfaces = new XDocument(new XElement("Interfaces", 
                                        new XElement("Interface",                                                         
                                         new XElement("vlan-tagging", XElement.EmptySequence),
                                            new XElement("unit",
                                            new XElement("vlan-id", "10"),
                                            new XElement("family", 
                                                new XElement("inet", 
                                                   new XElement("address",
                                                       new XElement("name", "10.10.1.23/24")))))))); ;
        var intf = new List<string> { "em0", "em1", "em2" };

        foreach (var i in intf)
            interfaces.Element("Interfaces").Element("Interface").AddFirst(new XElement("name", i));

        interfaces.Save("Interfaces.xml");            
    }
```

Comment: Все верно! Вы также ответили , как и здесь:)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898948/where-is-the-error-linq-to-xml

Я там добавил перед циклом строчку, эта ошибка ушла. но мой цикл (по-ходу неправильный) выдает мне иолько последний i , то есть em2. А предполагается, что все три. Может вам очевидно тут все! Мне не видно...

Comment: вы снова совершаете ту же самую ошибку. Инициализировать надо не **intf**, а **interfaces**. Более того, зачем вам вообще запихивать всю логику заполнения xml-документа в цикл, если большая ее часть вполняет одно и то же (и в итоге в получаете 2 абсолютно бесполезных прогона по циклу и неверный результат). Дополнил ответ, взгляните

Comment: DreamChild, я попробовал с вашими изменениями сделать. Результат такой, что по-ходу нельзя вырывать из всей конструкции строку для итерации.Тут одно за другим идет , так и XML файл строится.Исказился выходной XML. Получается тут надо посмотреть в мануалах как коллекции запихиваются в XML файлы в случае LINQ to XML.

Comment: Ну разумеется я не в курсе, какой конкретно xml  вы ожидаете получить, поэтому вполне логично,  что мой вариант может отличаться от желаемого вам. Однако очевидно, что это легко поправить, слегка переписав этот код в соответствии с вашими пожеланиями. Но в целом нужно сделать именно так

Comment: В целом да, Спасибо !!!

Comment: @DreamChild: по поводу дополнительного анализа со стороны компилятора, разработчики писали вот что: Было бы глупо не выдавать ошибку в случае, если компилятор _может_ доказать, что переменная будет инициализирована косвенным образом, т. к. _полностью_ эту задачу решить невозможно (это не что иное, как halting problem), а частичное решение зависело бы от глубины анализа и потенциально менялось бы от версии к версии — таким образом, программа, валидная в одной версии, могла оказаться невалидной в другой.

Comment: @DreamChild: ...Поэтому они сознательно не применяют flow analysis, чтобы на уровне стандарта языка определять, какая программа правильная, а какая нет.